# Salesforce.com: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: salesforce

I'm getting the following error when trying to test my Apex Test Class

Message:
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Stack Trace error:
Class.RenewalNotificationController.mergeExistingFields: line 321, column 1 Class.RenewalNotificationController.mergeAndCreateMail: line 227, column 1 Class.RenewalNotificationController.sendMail: line 177, column 1 Class.RenewalNotificationControllerTEST.testRenewalNotifications: line 71, column 1

Below is the Apex Test Class

I'll add my Apex Class shortly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!
Rommel

## Apex Test Class

```
public class RenewalNotificationControllerTEST {

public testMethod static void testRenewalNotifications() {

//==============30 Day Test================
Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test1', Renewal_Notice_Email__c = 'rmehta@apprivo.com', 
Probability = 5, Description = 'test', CloseDate = Date.today() + 5,Contract_Expires__c = Date.today() + 5, Sales_Engagement_Strategy__c = 'not null',
Amount = 1000, StageName = 'Awareness', Theater__c='NA');
insert opp1;

Renewal__c renewal1 = new Renewal__c(Renewal_Opportunity__c = opp1.Id, 
Serviced_Product_SKU__c = 'test SKU', Parent_Serial_Number__c = '123456', 
Serial_Number__c = 'SN123', Line_End_Date__c = Date.today() + 10);
insert renewal1;

//==============60 Day Test================
Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test2', Renewal_Notice_Email__c = 'rmehta@apprivo.com', 
Probability = 5, Description = 'test', CloseDate = Date.today() + 65,Contract_Expires__c = Date.today() + 65, Sales_Engagement_Strategy__c = 'not null',
Amount = 1000, StageName = 'Awareness', Theater__c='NA');
insert opp2;

Renewal__c renewal2 = new Renewal__c(Renewal_Opportunity__c = opp2.Id, 
Serviced_Product_SKU__c = 'test SKU', Parent_Serial_Number__c = '123456', 
Serial_Number__c = 'SN123', Line_End_Date__c = Date.today() + 20);
insert renewal2;

//==============90 Day Test================
Opportunity opp3 = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test3', Renewal_Notice_Email__c = 'rmehta@apprivo.com', 
Probability = 50, Description = 'test', CloseDate = Date.today() + 95, Contract_Expires__c = Date.today() + 95, Sales_Engagement_Strategy__c = 'not null',
Amount = 1000, StageName = 'Awareness', Theater__c='NA');
insert opp3;

Renewal__c renewal3 = new Renewal__c(Renewal_Opportunity__c = opp3.Id, 
Serviced_Product_SKU__c = 'test SKU', Parent_Serial_Number__c = '123456', 
Serial_Number__c = 'SN123', Line_End_Date__c = Date.today() + 10);
insert renewal3;

//==============-1 Day Test================
Opportunity opp4 = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test1', Renewal_Notice_Email__c = 'rmehta@apprivo.com', 
Probability = 5, Description = 'test', CloseDate = Date.today() - 5,Contract_Expires__c = Date.today() - 5, Sales_Engagement_Strategy__c = 'not null',
Amount = 1000, StageName = 'Awareness', Theater__c='NA');
insert opp4;

BrandTemplate bt = [Select Id from BrandTemplate Limit 1];
/* EmailTemplate template = new EmailTemplate(Name = 'testTemplate', 
FolderId = RenewalNotificationController.FOLDER_ID,
Subject = 'Test Subject {!Opportunity.CloseDate}',
Body = 'Test Body {!Opportunity.Name} <Renewals> \n {!Opportunity.Theater__c} ' +
'\n {!Opportunity.CloseDate} \nfrom a F5 rep', 
HtmlValue = 'Test Body {!Opportunity.Name} <Renewals> <br> {!Opportunity.Theater__c} ' +
'<br> {!Opportunity.CloseDate} <br>from a F5 rep',
TemplateType= 'HTML',
BrandTemplateId = bt.Id, TemplateStyle = 'freeForm');
insert template;*/
EmailTemplate template = [Select Id, Name, Subject, Body, HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where FolderId = :RenewalNotificationController.FOLDER_ID Limit 1];

Test.startTest();
RenewalNotificationController controller = new RenewalNotificationController();

List<SelectOption> options = controller.getFilterOptionItems();

controller.FilterOption = '30';
controller.createTaskSubject();
controller.onDateFilterChange();
List<RenewalNotificationController.OppWrapper> opportunities = controller.getRenewalOpportunities();
for (RenewalNotificationController.OppWrapper wrapper : opportunities) {
wrapper.setSelected(true);
} 
controller.SelectedTemplate = template.Id;
controller.onEmailTemplateChange();
controller.sendMail();

controller.FilterOption = '60';
controller.createTaskSubject();
controller.onDateFilterChange();
controller.sendMail();

controller.FilterOption = '90';
controller.createTaskSubject();
controller.onDateFilterChange(); 
controller.sendMail();

controller.FilterOption = '-1';
controller.createTaskSubject();
controller.onDateFilterChange();

controller.FilterOption = '-14';
controller.createTaskSubject();
controller.onDateFilterChange();

controller.FilterOption = '-30';
controller.createTaskSubject();
controller.onDateFilterChange();

controller.FilterOption = '-90';
controller.createTaskSubject();
controller.onDateFilterChange();

controller.getSuccessEmails();
controller.getFailureEmails();

controller.backToRenewals();

Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

## Apex Class

```
public class RenewalNotificationController {

    public String filterOption {get; set;}
    List<OppWrapper> wrapperList;
    public String NoOpportunityMessage {get; set;}
    public String selectedTemplate {get; set;}

    private String STAGE_NAME = 'Internal Education';
    private Integer PROBABILITY = 25;
    public static final String FOLDER_ID = '00l50000000vdRRAAY';

    //used on page2
    List<Opportunity> successEmails;
    List<Opportunity> failureEmails;

    private static final String REGEX = '\\{![a-zA-Z\\._]*\\}';

    private Map<String, String> opportunityFields;

    public RenewalNotificationController(){
     filterOption = 'none';


        opportunityFields = new Map<String, String>();
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.Account}', 'Account.Name');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.CloseDate}', 'CloseDate');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.Amount}', 'Amount');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.Description}', 'Description');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.Name}', 'Name');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.Probability}', 'Probability');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.Contract_Expires__c}', 'Contract_Expires__c');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.OwnerEmail}', 'Owner.Email');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.OwnerFullName}', 'Owner.Name');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.OwnerFirstName}', 'Owner.FirstName');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.OwnerLastName}', 'Owner.LastName');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.OwnerPhone}', 'Owner.Phone');
        opportunityFields.put('{!Opportunity.OwnerTitle}', 'Owner.Title');

        onDateFilterChange();
    }


    public List<OppWrapper> getRenewalOpportunities() {
        return wrapperList;
    }

    public void onEmailTemplateChange() {
        System.debug('onEmailTemplateChange()');
        //List<SelectOption> options = getEmailTemplates();
        for (OppWrapper wrapper : wrapperList) {
            //Boolean selected = wrapper.getSelected();
            //unccoment thhis if only the selecyted ones should change
            //if (selected) {
                //String template = (selectedTemplate == null) ? options.get(0).getValue() : selectedTemplate;
                wrapper.setEmailTemplate(selectedTemplate);
            //}
        }
    }

    public void onDateFilterChange() {

        System.debug('selectedTemplate = ' + selectedTemplate);
        System.debug('f1 = ' + filterOption);

        if(filterOption != 'none'){
       String queryString = 'select Id, Renewal_Notice_Email__c, Probability, OwnerId, Owner.Email, Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName, Owner.Name, Owner.Phone, Owner.Title, Name, LastActivityDate, Description, CloseDate, Contract_Expires__c, Amount, Account.Name, AccountId From Opportunity Where OwnerId = \'' + UserInfo.getUserID() + '\' AND Id IN (select Renewal_Opportunity__c from Renewal__c) AND Probability > 0 AND Probability < 100' ; 

       Date startDate;
       Date endDate;

       //Determine the end and start dates for the renewal query
   if(filterOption == '30'){
        queryString += 'AND (Contract_Expires__c = THIS_MONTH OR Contract_Expires__c = NEXT_MONTH)';
       }else if(filterOption == '60'){
        startDate = Date.newInstance(Date.today().year(),Date.today().Month() + 2,1);
        endDate = Date.newInstance(Date.today().year(),Date.today().Month() + 2,  Date.daysInMonth(startDate.year(),startDate.Month()));
        queryString += 'AND Contract_Expires__c >= :startDate AND Contract_Expires__c <= :endDate';
       }else if(filterOption == '90'){
        startDate = Date.newInstance(Date.today().year(),Date.today().Month() + 3,1);
        endDate = Date.newInstance(Date.today().year(),Date.today().Month() + 3,  Date.daysInMonth(startDate.year(),startDate.Month()));
        queryString += 'AND Contract_Expires__c >= :startDate AND Contract_Expires__c <= :endDate';
   }else if(filterOption == '-1'){
startDate = Date.today().addDays(-14);
        endDate = Date.today().addDays(-1);
        queryString += 'AND Contract_Expires__c > :startDate AND Contract_Expires__c <= :endDate';          
       }else if(filterOption == '-14'){
        startDate = Date.today().addDays(-30);
        endDate = Date.today().addDays(-14);
        queryString += 'AND Contract_Expires__c > :startDate AND Contract_Expires__c <= :endDate';
       }else if(filterOption == '-30'){
        startDate = Date.today().addDays(-89);
        endDate = Date.today().addDays(-30);
        queryString += 'AND Contract_Expires__c >= :startDate AND Contract_Expires__c <= :endDate';
       }else if(filterOption == '-90'){
        endDate = Date.today().addDays(-90);
        queryString += 'AND Contract_Expires__c <= :endDate';
       }      

       system.debug('q1 ' + queryString);
       List<Opportunity> opportunities = Database.query(queryString);

       System.debug('opportunities size=' + opportunities.size());
       //to set message if no opp are found
       noOpportunityMessage = '';
       if (opportunities.size() == 0) {
           noOpportunityMessage = 'No Opportunities found for the selected criteria.';
       }

       //create wrapper
       wrapperList = new List<OppWrapper>();
       List<SelectOption> options = getEmailTemplates();
       for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
           OppWrapper wrapper = new OppWrapper();
           wrapper.setOpportunity(opp);
           wrapper.setSelected(false);
           wrapperList.add(wrapper);
           String template = (selectedTemplate == null) ? options.get(0).getValue() : selectedTemplate;
           wrapper.setEmailTemplate(template);
       }
        }
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getFilterOptionItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('none','-None-'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('30','30 Day Notice'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('60','60 Day Notice'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('90','90 Day Notice'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('-1','1 Day Lapse Notice'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('-14','14 Day Lapsed Notice'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('-30','30 Day Lapsed Notice'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('-90','90 Day Lapsed Notice'));
        return options;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getEmailTemplates() {
        List<EmailTemplate> templates = [Select e.Name, e.Id From EmailTemplate e where e.FolderId= :FOLDER_ID Order By e.Name];
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(EmailTemplate t : templates) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(t.id,t.name));
        }

        return options;
    }

    /*
    * Action method called from the page
    */
    public PageReference sendMail() {
                //array for holding the mails
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        //create a map so that we can avoid queries to get template details.
        Map<ID, TemplateDetails> emailTemplateMap = new Map<ID, TemplateDetails>();

        //get selected checkboxes
        for (OppWrapper wrapper : wrapperList) {
            Boolean selected = wrapper.getSelected();
            if (selected) {
                String emailTemplateId = wrapper.getEmailTemplate();
                System.debug('sendmail(): opp = ' + wrapper.getOpportunity().Name + ', Template ID = ' + emailTemplateId);
                //check if template exists in map
                TemplateDetails templateDetails = emailTemplateMap.get(emailTemplateId);
                if (templateDetails == null) {
                    //get the subject and body of the template
                    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [Select e.Name, e.Subject, e.Id, e.HtmlValue, e.Body From EmailTemplate e Where e.Id= :emailTemplateId];
                    templateDetails = new TemplateDetails();
                    emailTemplateMap.put(emailTemplateId, templateDetails);
                    templateDetails.setEmailTemplate(emailTemplate);
                    //get documents for this email template and add it to template details
                    List<DocumentAttachmentMap> attachments = [Select d.DocumentId From DocumentAttachmentMap d 
                            Where d.ParentId = :emailTemplateId];
                    templateDetails.setDocumentIds(attachments);
                }

                //create the merged email and add it array
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = mergeAndCreateMail(templateDetails, wrapper.getOpportunity());
                mails.add(mail);

            }
        }
        if (mails.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        System.debug('Now Sending email ');
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultArr = Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
        System.debug('Send email result = ' + resultArr[0]);
        failureEmails = new List<Opportunity>();
        successEmails = new List<Opportunity>();
        Integer i = 0;
        for (OppWrapper wrapper : wrapperList) {
            Boolean selected = wrapper.getSelected();
            if (selected) {
                Messaging.SendEmailResult result = resultArr[i];
                if (result.isSuccess()) { //error
                    successEmails.add(wrapper.getOpportunity());    
                } else {
                    failureEmails.add(wrapper.getOpportunity());
                } 
                i++;
            }

        }       
        //90 day notifications will update opportunity probability to 30% and stage to 'Internal Education'.
        //if (filterOption.equals('2')) {
            updateOpportunities();
        //}
        //create tasks for the emails sent
        createTask();
        return Page.renewalNotificationResult;
    }

    /*
     * Called from the result page to go back to the renewals
     */
    public PageReference backToRenewals() {
        return Page.renewalNotification;
    }

/*******************mail methods****************************/

    private Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mergeAndCreateMail(TemplateDetails templateDetails, Opportunity opp) {
        EmailTemplate emailTemplate = templateDetails.getEmailTemplate();

        //merge existing fields
        String subject = emailTemplate.Subject;
        subject = mergeExistingFields(subject, opp);

        String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
        System.debug('htmlBody = ' + htmlBody);
        htmlBody = mergeExistingFields(htmlBody, opp);

        String textBody = emailTemplate.Body;
        textBody = mergeExistingFields(textBody, opp);

        //merge dynamic fields
        Set<String> mergeFieldSet = getMergeFieldSet(subject, htmlBody, textBody);

        //we have to make the merge fields on the object type. 
        Map<String, List<String>> mergeFieldMap = getMergeFieldMap(mergeFieldSet);
        System.debug('mergeFieldMap = ' + mergeFieldMap);

        //now for each key in the array we need to make a dynamic soql
        //example of mergeFieldMap = {Opportunity=(Business_Type__c, Theater__c)}
        for (String s : mergeFieldMap.keySet()) {
            List<String> columnsForSoql = mergeFieldMap.get(s);
            String sColumnsForSoql = getListAsString(columnsForSoql);
            SObject sObj = null;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase('opportunity')) {
                sObj = Database.query('Select ' + sColumnsForSoql + ' from opportunity where id = \'' + opp.id + '\'');
            } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase('user')) {
                sObj = Database.query('Select ' + sColumnsForSoql + ' from user where id = \'' + UserInfo.getUserID() + '\'');
            }
            subject = mergeDynamicFields(subject, sObj, mergeFieldSet);
            htmlBody = mergeDynamicFields(htmlBody, sObj, mergeFieldSet);
            textBody = mergeDynamicFields(textBody, sObj, mergeFieldSet);
        }

        //now get the renewals
        List<Renewal__c> renewals = getRenewals(opp);
        if (htmlBody.indexOf('<Renewals>') != -1 || htmlBody.indexOf('&lt;Renewals&gt;') != -1) {
            String htmlRenewals = printHtmlRenewals(renewals);
            if (htmlBody.indexOf('<Renewals>') != -1) {
                Integer startIndex = htmlBody.indexOf('<Renewals>');
                htmlBody = htmlBody.substring(0, startIndex)  + htmlRenewals + htmlBody.substring(startIndex + 10); //10 is length of renewals
            }
            if (htmlBody.indexOf('&lt;Renewals&gt;') != -1) {
                Integer startIndex = htmlBody.indexOf('&lt;Renewals&gt;');
                htmlBody = htmlBody.substring(0, startIndex)  + htmlRenewals + htmlBody.substring(startIndex + 16); //10 is length of renewals
            }

        }

        if (textBody.indexOf('<Renewals>') != -1 || textBody.indexOf('&lt;Renewals&gt;') != -1) {
            String textRenewals = printTextRenewals(renewals);
            if (textBody.indexOf('<Renewals>') != -1) {
                Integer startIndex = textBody.indexOf('<Renewals>');
                textBody = textBody.substring(0, startIndex)  + textRenewals + textBody.substring(startIndex + 10); //10 is length of renewals
            }
            if (textBody.indexOf('&lt;Renewals&gt;') != -1) {
                Integer startIndex = textBody.indexOf('&lt;Renewals&gt;');
                textBody = textBody.substring(0, startIndex)  + textRenewals + textBody.substring(startIndex + 16); //16 is length of renewals
            }
        }

        //now set the mail object
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(textBody);
        String[] userEmail = new List<String>();
        userEmail.add(getUserEmail()); 
        mail.setBccAddresses(userEmail);
        //set the attachments
        ID[] documentIds = templateDetails.getDocumentIds();
        if (documentIds != null) {
            System.debug('documentIds = ' + documentIds[0]);
            mail.setDocumentAttachments(documentIds);
        }

        //get the to Addresses
        String renewalNoticeEmail = opp.Renewal_Notice_Email__c;
        System.debug('renewalNoticeEmail = ' + renewalNoticeEmail);
        String[] toAddresses = renewalNoticeEmail.split(';'); //there maybe multiple
        mail.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
        return mail;
    }
private String mergeExistingFields(String text, Opportunity opp) {
            Set<String> existingFields = opportunityFields.keySet();
            for (String mergeField : existingFields) {
                System.debug('mergeField = ' + mergeField);
                Integer index = text.indexOf(mergeField);
                while (index != -1) {
                    String fieldSoqlName = opportunityFields.get(mergeField);
                    String value = '';

                    if (fieldSoqlName.startsWith('Account')) {
                        Account a = opp.Account;
                        fieldSoqlName = fieldSoqlName.substring(8);
                        value = (String) a.get(fieldSoqlName);
                    } else if (fieldSoqlName.startsWith('Owner')) {
                        User u = opp.Owner;
                        fieldSoqlName = fieldSoqlName.substring(6);
                        value = (String) u.get(fieldSoqlName);                                  
                    } else {
                        Object obj = opp.get(fieldSoqlName);
                        if (obj instanceof Date) {
                            Date dt = Date.valueOf(obj);
                            if (dt != null)
                                value = dt.month() + '/' + dt.day() + '/' + dt.year();
                            else
                                value = '';

                        } else {                                        
                            value = String.valueOf(obj);
                        }
                    }
                    if (value == null) value = '';

                    System.debug(fieldSoqlName + ' = ' + value);
                    Boolean more = text.length() > index + mergeField.length();
                    text = text.substring(0, index) + value + ((more) ? text.substring(index + mergeField.length()) : '');
                    index = text.indexOf(mergeField);       
                }
            }
            return text;
        }

        /*
         * Merges the fields retrieved by the dynamic query.
         */
        private String mergeDynamicFields(String text, SObject sObj, Set<String> mergeFieldSet) {

            for (String mergeField : mergeFieldSet) {
                Integer index = text.indexOf(mergeField);
                while (index != -1) {
                    String fieldValue = '';
                    String mergeFieldColumn = getMergeFieldColumn(mergeField);
                    System.debug('mergeFieldColumn = ' + mergeFieldColumn);
                    if (sObj != null) {
                        Object obj = sObj.get(mergeFieldColumn);
                        if (obj instanceof Date) {
                            Date dt = Date.valueOf(obj);
                            if (dt != null)
                                fieldValue = dt.month() + '/' + dt.day() + '/' + dt.year();                                             
                        } else {  
                            if (obj != null)                                      
                                fieldValue = String.valueOf(obj);
                        }
                    }
                    System.debug('fieldValue = ' + fieldValue);
                    if (fieldValue == null) fieldValue = '';
                    Boolean more = text.length() > index + mergeField.length();
                    text = text.substring(0, index) + fieldValue + ((more) ? text.substring(index + mergeField.length()) : '');
                    index = text.indexOf(mergeField);       
                }
            }

            return text;
        }

    /*
     * adds the merge fields to the Set. Set ensures they are added only once
     */
        private void extractMergeFields(String str, Set<String> mergeFieldSet) {
            Pattern p = pattern.compile(REGEX);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(str); // get a matcher object
            while(m.find()) {
                System.debug('group(): ' + m.group(0));
                mergeFieldSet.add(m.group(0));
            }
        }


        //example - mergeFieldSet = {{!Opportunity.Business_Type__c}, {!Opportunity.Theater__c}}
        private Set<String> getMergeFieldSet(String subject, String htmlBody, String textBody) {
                Set<String> mergeFieldSet = new Set<String>();
                extractMergeFields(subject, mergeFieldSet);
                extractMergeFields(htmlBody, mergeFieldSet);
                extractMergeFields(textBody, mergeFieldSet);
                System.debug('mergeFieldSet = ' + mergeFieldSet); 
                return mergeFieldSet;
        }

    /*
    * takes the merge field set and creates a map
    * Map is like - Opportunity = List {Theater__c, SomeField}
    */
    private Map<String, List<String>> getMergeFieldMap(Set<String> mergeFieldSet) {
        Map<String, List<String>> mergeFieldMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();
        for (String mergeField : mergeFieldSet) {
                String mergeFieldObject = getMergeFieldObject(mergeField);
                String mergeFieldColumn = getMergeFieldColumn(mergeField);
                List<String> mergeFieldColumnList = mergeFieldMap.get(mergeFieldObject);
                if (mergeFieldColumnList == null) {
                        mergeFieldColumnList = new List<String>();
                        mergeFieldMap.put(mergeFieldObject, mergeFieldColumnList);      
                }
                mergeFieldColumnList.add(mergeFieldColumn);
        }
        return mergeFieldMap;
    }

    private String getMergeFieldObject(String mergeField) {
        Integer index = mergeField.indexOf('.');
        if (index != -1)
            return mergeField.substring(2, index);
        return  mergeField;
    }

    private String getMergeFieldColumn(String mergeField) {
        Integer index = mergeField.indexOf('.');
        if (index != -1)
            return mergeField.substring(index + 1, mergeField.length() -1);
        return  mergeField;
    }

    private void updateOpportunities() {
        List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>();
        for (OppWrapper wrapper : wrapperList) {
            Boolean selected = wrapper.getSelected();
            if (selected) {
                Opportunity opp = wrapper.getOpportunity();
                Decimal prob = opp.Probability;
                if (prob == 5) {
                    opp.StageName = 'Research and Internal Education';
                    opp.Probability = PROBABILITY;
                    opportunities.add(opp);             
                }
            }
        }
        update opportunities;
    }

    private void createTask() {
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        for (OppWrapper wrapper : wrapperList) {
            Boolean selected = wrapper.getSelected();
            if (selected) {
                Task t = new Task();
                t.WhatId = wrapper.getOpportunity().Id;
                t.ActivityDate = Date.today();
                t.Description = 'A renewal notice has been sent to the following recipient(s): ' + wrapper.getOpportunity().get('Renewal_Notice_Email__c');
                t.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserID();
                t.Status = 'Completed';
                t.Subject = createTaskSubject();
                taskList.add(t);            
            }
        }
        if (taskList.size() > 0) {
            insert taskList;
        }
    }

    public String createTaskSubject() {
        String txt = '';
        if (filterOption.equals('30')) { //60 days
            txt = '30';
        }else if (filterOption.equals('60')) { //60 days
            txt = '60';
        }else if (filterOption.equals('90')) { //60 days
            txt = '90';
        }else if (filterOption.equals('-1')) { //60 days
            txt = '-1';
        }else if (filterOption.equals('-14')) {  //90 days
            txt = '-14';
        }else if (filterOption.equals('-30')) {  //90 days
            txt = '-30';
        }else if (filterOption.equals('-90')) {  //90 days
            txt = '-90';
        }
        return 'Email: F5 Maintenance ' + txt + ' Day Renewal Notice';
    }

private String getUserEmail() {
User activeUser = [Select Email From User where Username = :UserInfo.getUserName() limit 1];
return activeUser.Email;
}

/* *************************renewal methods ********************************* */        
    private List<Renewal__c> getRenewals(Opportunity opp) {
        String oppId = opp.Id;
        List<Renewal__c> renewals  = [Select r.Serviced_Product_SKU__c, r.Serial_Number__c, r.Parent_Serial_Number__c, r.Line_End_Date__c From Renewal__c r Where Renewal_Opportunity__c =:oppId  OR Merged_to_Opportunity__c = :oppId];
        return renewals;
    }

    private String printHtmlRenewals(List<Renewal__c> renewals) {
        String htmlRenewals = '<table>';
        for (Renewal__c r : renewals) {
            htmlRenewals += '<tr>';
            htmlRenewals += '<td align=\'left\' width=\'20%\'>' + r.Serviced_Product_SKU__c + '</td>';
                htmlRenewals += '<td align=\'left\' width=\'15%\'>' + r.Parent_Serial_Number__c + '</td>';
                htmlRenewals += '<td align=\'left\' width=\'15%\'>' + r.Serial_Number__c + '</td>';
                Date dt = r.Line_End_Date__c;
                htmlRenewals += '<td align=\'left\' width=\'20%\'>' + dt.month() + '/' + dt.day() + '/' + dt.year() + '</td>';
            htmlRenewals += '</tr>';
        }
        htmlRenewals += '</table>';
        return htmlRenewals;
    }

    private String printTextRenewals(List<Renewal__c> renewals) {
        String textRenewals = '\n';
        for (Renewal__c r : renewals) {
        textRenewals += r.Serviced_Product_SKU__c + '\t';
            textRenewals += r.Parent_Serial_Number__c + '\t';
            textRenewals += r.Serial_Number__c + '\t';
            textRenewals += Date.valueOf(r.Line_End_Date__c) + '\n';
        }
        textRenewals += '\n';
        return textRenewals;
    }


/* 
 *****************util method ********************************* 
 */

    private String getListAsString(List<String> columnsForSoql) {
        String retStr = '';
        for (String s : columnsForSoql) {
                if (retStr != '') retStr += ',';
                retStr += s;
        }
        System.debug('getListAsString(): retStr = ' + retStr);
        return retStr;
    }

/*
 *****************getters *********************************
 */

    public List<Opportunity> getSuccessEmails() {
        return successEmails;   
    }

    public List<Opportunity> getFailureEmails() {
        return failureEmails;   
    }

    /*
     *******************wrapper class **************
     */
    public class OppWrapper {

        private Opportunity opportunity;
        private String emailTemplate;
        private Boolean selected;

        public void setOpportunity(Opportunity opportunity) {
                this.opportunity = opportunity; 
        }

        public Opportunity getOpportunity() { return this.opportunity; }

        public void setEmailTemplate(String emailTemplate) {
                this.emailTemplate = emailTemplate;     
        }

        public String getEmailTemplate() { return this.emailTemplate; } 


        public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
                this.selected = selected;     
        }

        public Boolean getSelected() { return this.selected; } 
    }

        /*
         *********holder class for template details ******************
         */
        private class TemplateDetails {

                private EmailTemplate emailTemplate;
                private ID[] documentIds;

                public void setEmailTemplate(EmailTemplate emailTemplate) { this.emailTemplate = emailTemplate; }

                public EmailTemplate getEmailTemplate() { return this.emailTemplate; }  

                public void setDocumentIds(List<DocumentAttachmentMap> attachments) { 
                        if (attachments != null && attachments.size() > 0) {
                                documentIds = new ID[attachments.size()];
                                for (Integer i = 0; i < attachments.size(); i++) {
                                        documentIds[i] = attachments.get(i).DocumentId;
                                }
                        }
                }

                public List<ID> getDocumentIds() { return this.documentIds; }     
        }     
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really a good place to dump a whole lot of source code and say "There is a null reference exception in here, can you please find it for me?". Try to narrow it down by reducing your code to the minimum amount required to trigger the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace is telling you where the problem is: `Class.RenewalNotificationController.mergeExistingFields: line 321, column 1`.

Go to that line and look at the code.  Back up from that point and see how you might have gotten a NULL value there.  Look at your debug log to see the call path and observe the values of the fields passed to that function.  Add additional `System.Debug()` statements if necessary.

You have everything you need to figure out the problem, and there's not much SO can do without having access to the code in your Salesforce Org.